# Adding a Period After the Page Number When Using Idxlayout

Tags: luatex, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\Large

\noindent Some words.\index{\textbf{How to add a period after the page number?}}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the index:

[image]

QUESTION: How may the above code be modified in order to place a period after the page number for each (ordinary) index entry? (I compile the code with `lualatex` if that makes a difference.)

Thank you.

Comment: You want to use a special `.ist` file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didn't we do this in an earlier question?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand\dotify[1]{#1.}
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\Large

\noindent Some words.\index{\textbf{How to add a period after the page number?}|dotify}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems like something I would have likely asked before, but when I checked all my questions with the indexing tag, I didn't find the question. Prior to that, I spent a little time searching the site---figuring that somebody must have asked this question before---but I turned up nothing. So, I posted the question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: As the document I am working seems to have periods at the end of all of the index entries, is there a way, perhaps, of declaring that to happen automatically, as opposed to placing the `|dotify` at the end of every `\index` command? Thank you.

Comment: do you really have periods after every number, even for more than 1 page, so an index entry foo on page 4, 6 and 10 appears as  "foo 4., 6., 10. "  ?

Comment: assuming you just want a `.` at the end  use a makeindex style (you _definitely_ have answers on how to use ist files) and set `delim_t .` so it pust a `.` at the end of  the page list.

Comment: I recall that the last listed page of every entry has a period; of course, if an entry has multiple pages associated with it, the first through the penultimate are separated by commas. Let me think about the comment I posted to you a little while ago, it may not be as simple a task as I thought.

Comment: @mlchristians that is what the `delim_t` setting will do, leave commas as default and put a `.` at the end.

Comment: Many thanks @David Carlisle.